# Can use Google's Cloud Messaging for iOS in a hybrid app?

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, google-cloud-messaging

I am planning to build a "hybrid app" using PhoneGap which needs to have a iOS push notification engine.

And I want to use [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging) for sending push notifications to the iOS (I have used this for sending notifications to Android).

My questions here are:

1. Can I use Google Cloud Messaging for iOS in an hybrid app (using PhoneGap's https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)?
2. Are there any changes that I may have to do while using the above plugin?

I have used the above PhoneGap plugin to receive notifications from GCM and APNS separately but this time I want to use the GCM for both iOS and Android.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I also have used GCM and APNS separately for send push notifications to Android and iOs devices independently.

For all the documentation I've read, GCM for iOs devices is an approach of the APNS service but using the same structure that GCM is using for Android devices. I think that if you have used the APNService, you have found all the hard steps (certificates, using strictly a Mac for some things, ...) so, answering to your questions:

1. Yes, you can use the GCM for iOs with Phonegap plugin because GCM Server sends the data that PhoneGap's plugin is ready to receive (as you can see in the [GCM Server Reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#table1) there are some data specific for APNS (nothing that you don't know if you have worked with APNS)).

> If you are preparing a native app for iOs, you should see the [GCM iOs Client](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client) documentation because you will have to use the [iOs API](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/api/gcm/) but it's not your problem.

2. I don't expect that you have to do changes while using PhoneGap's plugin. You will only have to use PhoneGap's implementation for iOs devices and get ready to receive push notifications (but if you have some troubles, please, I will be pleased to know them).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But before I start receiving data from GCM, I need to register my device with the GCM (even when running my App on iOS). I tried by explicitly setting the "Sender ID" even while on the iOS device but I keep getting the APNS's "regID" instead of the "GCM's" token. Do you have suggestion to overcome this when using the above PhoneGap plugin? I am still looking into this but thought you might have few suggestions for me to test this out.

Comment: Is there the possibility that you are doing the request to the APNS URL instead of the GCM URL? It's the first thing that comes to my mind

Comment: Yes, as you must be knowing that the PhoneGap plugin we are using handles this internally and call the relevant URL (APNS or GCM) depending on the device type. By the look of the token I am getting, I am pretty sure that its using the APNS URL and not the GCM when on the iOS device. And I checked to find that I can successfully send the push notification using that token via APNS.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Is your issue resolved ? I am also trying to build a phonegap app sencha app which should support ios and android push notification only through GCM (for both).  I am not able to find the right plugin for phonegap gcm and its corresponding config.xml entry. I am able to use GCM for android and APN for ios successfully using phonegap pushnotification pgp plugin but I want to have one interface only as GCM. Can you please guide if your issue resolved and which plugin you have used in config.xml for phonegap build